# Define custom StyleData in webMathematica application

Tags: stylesheet, webmathematica, traditional-form

I need to set some options to customize the style of TraditionalForm expressions inside a webMathematica application. I asked to Wolfram's Techcnical Support if StyleSheet can be used from within webMathematica and the answer is no. It means all styles, different from defaults, have to be explicitly inserted in the  code. I think this is very annoying, because if I want to produce a styled web site I don't want to repeat options for all pages. Just to make an example from my real case:

In my front end I have the following TraditionalForm customization:

```
Cell[StyleData["TraditionalForm"],
 ScriptMinSize->9*(40/14),
 FontFamily->Arial,
 FontColor->RGBColor[0,0,1],
 FontSize->40]
```

Considering that I cannot use StyleSheet, and the StyleData cannot be defined in the kernel, the only solution is:

```
<msp:evaluate>
MSPBlock[{$$fun}, MSPFormat[Style[$$fun, FontSize->40, ScriptMinSize->9*(40/14), FontFamily->Arial, FontColor->RGBColor[0,0,1]], TraditionalForm, "PNG"]]
</msp:evaluate>
```

The problem is that I have many pages and each page has many pieces of code generating such expressions. 
Any suggestion about how to define the custom StyleData "TraditionalForm" in the kernel or alternatives to my solution?